# How to find specific characters using PHP

Tags: php, regex, stripos

My task was to create a PHP file that will check a name coming from HTML GET and the basis are the following:

- It can be from a-z in small or capital letters
- 25 or less characters length
- Also add the TM Trademark as an exception

I don't know whether I will use REGEX or STRIPOS for this. My professor is asking me to write this in PHP. Some example scenarios:

```
1. AdriaN = allow
2. $tackoverFlow = not allowed
3. StackoverFl0w = allowed
4. ™ Stack Over Flow ™ = Allowed
5. StækOverFlow = not allowed
```

Here's what I have come up with so far, can this be improved upon?

```
 $pattern = '/[a-zA-Z0-9\$\™]{1,24}$/';
```

Comment: It can be from `a-b in small or capital letters` ?? You mean `a-z` ? Also `StackoverFl0w` has the number `0` so are numbers allowed as well?

Comment: Yes from a-z. A word with a combination of numbers are also okay.

Comment: More details are needed... what about: http://regex101.com/r/mA1yU3/1

Comment: Don't forget to tell your professor that it was @Enissay who solved the problem :)

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/xU5uA7/1

Comment: Will do, I will add your name to credits :)

My version is 

$pattern = '/[a-zA-Z0-9\$\™]{1,24}$/'; It also works!

Comment: @Enissay [this is a whole lot shorter](http://regex101.com/r/mA1yU3/2)

Comment: @scrowler: the question mark is useless

Comment: @user3546768: are leading or trailing whitespaces allowed?

Comment: I thought a `$` was not permitted, but you have it in your code sample?

Comment: @Enissay It allows more than 25 characters in length!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your samples, you've some spaces inside that are allowed. So I suggest this regex:

```
/^[a-z\d™][a-z\d\s™]{1,24}(?<!\s)$/im
```

`m` multi-line and `i` case-insensitive modifiers are set

If Professor asks for `(?<!\s)`, reply back it's a ***negative lookbehind*** to ensure that there's no trailing spaces at the end.

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/eN1sA1/1)**